# Bottom of UILabel text cut off when using adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

When the font size of my UILabel gets adjusted to fit the width of the label, the bottom of the text gets cut off. Here's a screenshot of the debug view:

[image]

The UILabel has the following characteristics:

- **System font** (semibold, 36pt)
- **numberOfLines** = 1
- **baselineAdjustment** = .alignCenters
- **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints** = false
- **auto-layout constraints**: top, left and right pinned are pinned, and there is no bottom or height constraint
- **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** = true, **minimumScaleFactor** = 0.1
- No text by default, the text is given after initialization
- **lineBreakMode** = .byWordWrapping

Additional elements:

- This only happens when the font size does get reduced. If the text is shorter and fits at the original font size, it's not cut off.
- If I manually change the font size so that the text fits, it does not get cut off. It only happens when it automatically adjusts to that font size.

Things that did not work:

- Use **.attributedText** rather than **.text** property
- Call sizeToFits, setNeedsLayout()/layoutIfNeeded()
- Setting a long text by default to the label
- Trying all settings of **baselineAdjustment** ( setting to .none worked, see answer)

*(As I was typing this question, I tried changing **baselineAdjustment** settings again to confirm it didn't work and this time, it worked. See answer.)*

Comment: "bottom/height is free" so there is *no* height constraint, correct?

Comment: @AhmadF Correct (I am editing to clarify), but I have found the fix to the bug while typing out my question. Check the answer below. Thank you for your help!

Comment: which font family you are using?
 Use Arial or any common font and test and check same occurs or not

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich thanks, but fix available the answer I posted :-) Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I was typing out the answer and going back on every setting I had tried, setting the label's **baselineAdjustement** to **.none** fixed the issue.

```
label.baselineAdjustment = .none
```

FYI, the following documentations extracts were confusing to me:

From the documentation of [UILabel baselineAdjustement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620524-baselineadjustment):

> The **default** value of this property is **alignBaselines**.

From the documentation of [UIBaselineAdjustment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibaselineadjustment):

> .none: This is the **default** adjustment.

I'd be interested if anyone could confirm in the comments, but from my experiments, **.none** doesn't seem to be the **default** baselineAdjustment of **UILabel**. I had to specifically set the baselineAdjustment to .none to fix the bug mentioned in the question.

Comment: yes, the default value of `baselinedAdjustment` is `.alignBaselines`

Comment: How do you override the UILabel's baselineAdjustment property in a custom UILabel?